# Hamcrest: How to test for multiple properties of an object

Tags: java, assert, hamcrest

```
rules=[{type:"path", value:"abc"},{type:"cookie", value:"xyz"}, ...]
```

I want to find if the array contains an object with properties  (`type=path` and `value=abc`)

I tried something like this:
`assertThat(rules, hasItem(hasProperty("type", equals("path"))));`

But I didn't find a way to combine two `hasProperty` methods. Can someone help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following will try to apply each Matcher in the `allOf()` check to each item in `rules`:

```
    assertThat(rules,
            hasItem(allOf(hasProperty("type", equalTo("path")),
                    hasProperty("value", equalTo("abc")))));
```